# VBA code not filling in date

Tags: vba

I'd like my VBA code to fill the date field on a particular website with the date 1990-02-22.

Here is the source code of the element whose field I need to fill in:

```
<input id="mainDriver.dateOfBirth" name="mainDriver.dateOfBirth" class="sg-Input user-success" data-date-split-input="true" max="2015-08-14" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-nopicker="true" type="date" value="">
```

I've tried several variations of the following code:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("mainDriver.dateOfBirth").Value = DateValue(1990 - 02 - 22)
```

e.g. I've also tried this:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("mainDriver.dateOfBirth").Value = DateValue("February 22, 1990")
```

... which seems to be the way to express the DateValue argument according to what I searched online.

In both of the cases above the page is not affected - and no error is provided in the code to debug.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you'd like to see exactly where that field is, you could manually fill in the IE fields up until that point. The IE page is [here](https://www.aami.com.au/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-get-a-quote.html).

And you could use the following example for address information when you get to those fields:

Postcode: COOKS HILL, 2300, NSW

Street Address: 33 Bull Street

Otherwise you could randomly choose / select the values of the other fields, from the dropdowns etc.

Comment: Hi @Bond - thanks for the edit. I deleted my answer though as it turned out not to be an answer. I think I must be seeing things because it looked as though the following code worked but when I ran it again, it simply did nothing :/     `getElementById("mainDriver.dateOfBirth").Value = "1990-02-10"`

Comment: Okay, this is bizarre! I filled in the rest of the fields and got a quote to be generated. When I look up the details of the quote on this final page, it shows 1990-02-10 as the DOB. Why would it actually store this DOB value but not display the DOB in the field / DOB box when the relevant bit of code is executed?

Comment: Thanks @WanderingFool - a useful edit indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. It was a matter of copying the format of date shown in the source code, i.e.

```
max="2015-08-14" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
```

... and then simply using the value property. So the following worked:

```
IE.document.getElementById("mainDriver.dateOfBirth").Value = "1990-02-10"
```

For some reason it doesn't actually display the DOB when the code is excecuted but the date is stored and used properly, thus allowing you to finish fill in the form.

Otherwise thanks for looking!

Comment: You'll have to trigger the `onchange` event in order for the text to appear updated, like before with the dropdowns.